# SP 2013 Search Results web part

Tags: search-results, query

I am trying to create an org chart based on a persons department. I am using the Search Results web part in SP 2013 Enterprise. When I build the query I select the "Local People Results (system). I don't change the keyword filter. The property filter is set to contentclass equals manual value spspeople. I add the property filter to the Query Text and test it. It brings back all 814 relevant results. Which is correct. I have compared this to the user profiles in the admin console and it is correct. I then try to refine my search by selecting a department from the refiners. The problem is only 7 of the 22 departments are displayed to select from. I have completed searches for users I know are in departments that are not displaying and I can retrieve them and verify that the department is populated with the correct department.

When I click on refiners, I get a list of refiners to choose from. Where are those being populated from? Anyone have any ideas why only some of the departments are displaying?

Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the filter webpart builds its list of refiners based on a sample of your results. In [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9c906ad-7f43-4fc6-9cd7-afba1b374927/list-filter-webpart-not-showing-all-values?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious), someone found out that only the first 200 results are being considered when building the filter items. Therefore, it is very likely that out of 814 results, only 200 are being considered, and that would explain why only roughly a quarter of your refiners are showing up. [This post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5b0bb4-6816-4d61-a5fb-0fb7fb4eb837/sharepoint-2010-list-filter-web-part-return-only-first-200-items?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5b0bb4-6816-4d61-a5fb-0fb7fb4eb837/sharepoint-2010-list-filter-web-part-return-only-first-200-items?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c5b0bb4-6816-4d61-a5fb-0fb7fb4eb837/sharepoint-2010-list-filter-web-part-return-only-first-200-items?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) confirms it as a bug.

Comment: You links refer to a list view filter and SP 2010, not 2013. I do not think this i"bug" applies here because the search results return all 814 people but only shows the ability to refine the search on some of them.